# Moment js seconds over 0-59

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to add one year on current date

```
moment().add(1, "Y").format('YYYY-MM-DD\THH:MM:SS+00:00')
```

Sometimes output is like this `'2022-04-09T18:04:75+00:00'`. As you can see I have here 75 seconds and I really don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

`SS` - maps back to fractional seconds per the documentation
`s` or `ss` may be used instead to output seconds as desired

The fractional second is used to represent a non-integer second and as a result, some part of a second

Consider the following modification:

```js
moment().add(1, "Y").format('YYYY-MM-DD\THH:MM:ss+00:00')
```

Similarly for the minutes portion, you may want to modify the format to be as `mm` resulting in:

```js
moment().add(1, "Y").format('YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ss+00:00')
```